# Freeform email notifications going to spam

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

Hi does anyone know how to keep the email notifications from going to spam folder?

Answer (score 1):

Email that is sent from your server is often marked as spam, this is not anything to do with either Craft or Freeform but with the fact that the server you use may not be trusted by email providers. Read the article Brad recommended for some background info. Then do yourself a favour and use a transactional email service to deal with all the hassle for you, sending email from their servers. A lot of them are free for smaller use. I use Postmark, you can easily implement it in Craft, see https://postmarkapp.com/support/article/1019-use-postmark-to-send-emails-from-craft 
I've also used Sendgrid in Craft with succes (with a little help from this page https://mediasurgery.co.uk/video-episodes/craft/make-sure-those-crucial-emails-get-delivered-with-craft-cms-and-sendgrid). Others include Mailgun, Sparkpost, or just Google 'transactional email service' for others.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this but I really wanted to know how everyone else was solving the issue. I will give Postmark a try! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what is putting those emails in SPAM (your email client, SPAM software on your email server, etc.) and white-list the Freeform emails by email address, subject, etc.

Other than that, there are some great tips here (DKIM, SPF, etc.) you can use to help ensure reliably email delivery through code that lessens the chances of SPAM filters thinking the email is SPAM in the first place.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/